# Validate a user interface (NSButton) as user type in NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I know how I'd do this with NSTextView, but NSTextField doesn't seem to provide a way to access the `NSTextStorage` backing it, so I can't set myself as a delegate and process `-textStorageDidProcessEditing:`.

I have a `NSTextField` as part of a sheet.  If that text field is emtpy at any point, the OK button should be disabled until some input is provided.  That's basically all I'm looking to do, and I'm sure there's a really simple way to do this?

I tried:

```
[[[filenameInput cell] textStorage] setDelegate:self];
```

Thinking that `NSTextFieldCell` would provide the text storage (mostly since Xcode kindly auto-completed it for me) and then of course, did my validation via the delegate method:

```
-(void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    BOOL allowSubmit = ([[filenameInput stringValue] length] > 0)
        && (([relativePathSwitch state] == NSOnState) || ([[localPathInput stringValue] length] > 0));
    [createButton setEnabled:allowSubmit];
}
```

This compiles but causes a runtime error as `NSTextFieldCell` does not respond to `textStorage`.

What's the standard pattern I should be following here?  This must be one of those "every day" tasks for Cocoa devs, I imagine :)

[image: The Sheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what NSFormatter is for; create a subclass of NSFormatter and set an instance of it as your NSTextField's formatter, and let it validate the text the user enters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.  Sounds like it would be a more scalable solution. There is some cross-dependency between fields, but I assume this is accounted for.  Just working on something else right now, but will try this once I'm done and flag this is accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Always the way... I found it.  It's not listed on the page for NSTextFieldDelegate, or NSControlTextEditingDelegate, but on the page for NSControl itself.

The delegate method is: `-controlTextDidChange:`.